# Как вывести многострочный текст в ноде Graphviz

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphviz

Граф создается в цикле - данных много.
В аргумент label надо вывести многострочный текст с учетом фиксированной длины фигуры.
Решение с переводом строки "\n" не очень удобно.

Условный пример кода:

```
from graphviz import Graph

g = Graph('G', node_attr={'shape':'box'})
g.node('A', label='Структурированное хранение типовых проектно-конструкторских решений', 
       width='2.5', fixedsize='true')

g
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, что означает отсутствие ответа на мой вопрос - кажется, спросил о простой вещи...
Если нет решения, исключающее применения "\n", то у меня получилось следующее:

```
def multiline_label(label, align='\n', len_string=25):
    word_label = label.split(' ')
    count_char = 0
    label_out = ''
    for i, word in enumerate(word_label):
        count_char += len(word)
        if count_char <= len_string:
            label_out = ''.join(label_out + ' ' + word)
        else:
            label_out = ''.join(label_out + align)
            count_char = 0
    label_out = ''.join(label_out + ' ' + word)    
    return label_out

from graphviz import Graph

g = Graph('G', node_attr={'shape':'box'}, filename='my_comment.gv', format='svg')
label = 'Структурированное хранение типовых проектно-конструкторских решений'
g.node('A', label=multiline_label(label), style='rounded',
       width='2.5', fixedsize='false')
g
```

Спасибо, конечно...

Comment: "Не знаю, что означает отсутствие ответа на мой вопрос - кажется, спросил о простой вещи..." - отсутствие ответа в данном случае означает только то, что ваш вопрос не увидел человек, который знает ответ на ваш вопрос, или в целом знает как решить проблему. И если бы вопрос был простой, вы бы не задали его, не так ли?

Comment: Причину понял. Спасибо за разъяснение!